# When to declare a callback method Private or Protected in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I was taking a look at some best practices in ROR, and I noticed that callback methods are declared in the protected section instead of the private. I've always used private when declaring callback methods, so I was wondering if it is better to use protected and why. Is there any substantial difference in this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

`private` - only available to be accessed within the class that defines them.

`protected` - accessible in the class that defines them and in other classes which inherit from that class.

Comment: That's true, but I'm asking the effects of this within a ROR context.

Comment: By defining the callbacks `protected` it allows subclasses of your class to use them.
I guess if it is unlikely that you will subclass your model then leave them as private.

Comment: I got the same error when using protected. Seems that you need to use public for STI callbacks defined at parent level.